# Postman send request entirely constructed in pre-requisite script

Tags: postman

I have this below piece of code that generates me multiple orders in Pre-request Script section.
I dont need to have anything in "Body" section. But sending just [{}] in the body gives me 400 error.

```
var guid = (function() {
function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
        .toString(16)
        .substring(1);
}
return function() {
    return 'HolCal' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
        s4();
};
})();
var requestKeyNum = 2; 

var orders = [];
for (var i = 0; i < requestKeyNum; i++) {

var key = guid();
orders.push({
  "key": key,
  "tradeDate": "2019-07-03",
    "settleDate": "2019-07-04",
    "transactionCode": "B", 
    "fundingCurrencySecurity" :{
   "secId":1894823,
        "secType1": "CASH", 
        "secType2":"NA",
        "secType3":"NA", 
        "secType4":"NA", 
        "assetClass":"C",
        "exchangeCode":"",
        "tradeCurrencyCode":"USD",
        "maturityDate":null,
        "mortgageClass":null, 
        "investIdType":"D",
        "investId":"9999USD", 
        "clearingHouseCode":null, 
        "settlementLocation":"PHY", 
        "expirationDate":null, 
        "issueCountry":""
    }
    })

}


postman.setEnvironmentVariable("orders", JSON.stringify(orders));
```

Comment: Can you please give us information about the server?

Comment: Like? Sorry, I hit an endpoint using the above request after NTLM authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How must your generated body look like?
I assume, that you want so send you generated orders in your body.
If its true, you must reference to the orders variable in your body. Use {{orders}} in your body panel to do this.

Comment: I got rid of the [] (big braces) and just used {{orders}} in the body - that solved it. Thanks